# mysql query for order base on current time

Tags: mysql

mysql query for order base on current time
I just want to ask what would be the best query for sorting the time value.

ex. i have 5 records of time data type.

7:00

8:00

9:00

10:00

11:00

I want to sort the record base on the current time.

ex. if its already 9:00,
i want the out put to be :

9:00

10:00

11:00

7:00

8:00

is this possible? if so. what query would be the best approach?
thanks in advance. hope some one could answer my question.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: i was trying it. but then i cant get the output. i tried to look for order by base on condition but no luck. can you help me out sir?

Comment: why did my question down voted? sir Ullas got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause.

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `time_column` >= cast(now() as time) then 0 else 1 end, `time_column`;
```

Comment: Ill try your answer sir. Ill feed back after

Comment: It is now working sir. thank you so much.can you explain to me what is the purpose of giving the value 0 and 1 on the else. how does it affect the order?

Comment: i get it now. its a representation of true and false. if the statement is true. add to list. else put on the least part of the order. thank you so much sir Ullas. you helped me.